# elasticsearch: optimal performance for searching over lots of fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, lucene, tire

We are using elasticsearch with rails using the retire gem. Currently we index lots of fields (30+) of which only 6 are currently full text searchable (user name, user email, user title, etc.).

We want to move towards all fields being searachable. So, instead of just those 6 main fields being searchable all 30 (and potentially more) are searchable. By searchable I mean exact matches, prefixes, fuzzy matching and substring matches.

There are two strategies we are considering:

1) Index each field individually using a correct analyzer and tokenizer (already have that part figured out) to meet the searchability requirements desired.

2) Create an indexed text blob of all other fields and index that blob as a whole.

I am curious what the trade-offs are for the two above solutions. We are looking for:

1) Decent write performance. Our objects change often (this is an index of searchable users with profiles).

2) Ease of adding new fields to the index over time.

3) Of course, read performance.

Comment: Can your users define custom fields? If so, you should look into the section on Key/Value Woes here: https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/#keyvalue-woes

Comment: @AlexBrasetvik we are not allowing users to define custom fields, although there is a "label" field which contains an array of strings.